# How to get list of azure user turn off multiple factor authentication

Tags: java, azure, rest, multi-factor-authentication

I need to check MFA status of azure user by rest API or java SDK. Does anyone know the way to check it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, **MFA status** is not currently available in the Azure AD Graph API or the Microsoft Graph API, or any SDK. You could find the similar issue from Tony French's comment in this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/20249953-powershell-and-graph-api-support-for-managing-mult).

So far you could only use the two methods to check MFA status of azure user:

1. access the Azure portal page
2. use PowerShell with `Install-Module MSOnline`

For more information, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-userstates#change-state-using-powershell).

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work